# 10 meters from you vs. in 10 meters from you

Tags: grammar

I have seen both but as I am not a native speaker - which one is preferable? 
"There is a lion **in** 10 meters from you" vs " There is a lion 10 meters from you". "The truck had stopped **in** several meters from me" vs "The truck had stopped several meters from me" ?
Thanks!

Comment: Use of 'in' in these two examples is not correct. Although, you can use the word 'within' if you mean that "There is a lion within 10 metres of you".

Comment: Thanks a lot! "within" as I understand the word means inside a certain area. so, for example, the lion could be anywhere (in front of me, behind, to the left...) inside an area of 5 meters. But what if I see a lion. There it is - right in front of me! "OMG - there is a lion 10 meters from me" - would be the only correct choice?

Comment: *There is a lion ten meters from you* is just fine.

Comment: Occam's razor suggests to remove the words you can do without. *Within* is not necessary to relay the meaning.

Comment: @vickyace  - I agree! Road closed, water hot, I being silly )))) only joking... I understand you completely and am really grateful for your help!

Comment: "There is a lion 10 meters from you" just refers to the distance between you and a lion.  "There is a lion in 10 meters from you" is strange grammar, mainly because of the "from you".  Without the "from you", it would be the kind of statement you would here from a GPS.  The assumption would be that you are moving, and continuing in the same direction for 10 meters would put you face to face with a lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There is a lion **in** 10 meters from you" is incorrect.

"There is a lion 10 meters from you" means there is a lion, and its distance from you is 10 meters (or, you know, approximatively 10 meters insofar as the person talking to you didn't take out their measuring stick).

"There is a lion **within** 10 meters **of** you" means there is a lion, and its distance from you is equal to *or less than* 10 meters, i.e. its position is within the disk defined by you at its center and a 10 meter radius.

See [definition 2a here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/within) for the latter usage.

"The truck had stopped **in** several meters from me" is also incorrect, but is slightly closer to being correct, in that there is movement involved, not just being. You can use "in" when you're talking about an activity, and how it didn't, or won't, take more than a certain amount of meters. This is by analogy to the use of "in" with respect to time:

> "I finished my homework in just 30 minutes!"
>   "I'll be there in a second!"

As described in [definition 1.7 here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in#Preposition) and in the section called "**used for expressions of time**" [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in). In cases where distance is a relevant measurement that you would use in the same way you'd use a time measure, to say "this action happens within this spatial frame", then you can use it the same way :

> ["It's the ship that made the Kessel Run in less than twelve parsecs"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kessel_Run)

(that's a joke, because I'm pretty sure that in that quote "parsec" is mistakenly being used as a unit of time even though it's a unit of distance, but all the effort expended to rationalize it to make it valid indicates that it isn't *grammatically* wrong at least. Better example: )

> "This truck will need refuelling in 50 kilometers"

I note that one difference between that and the truck stopping 10 meters from you is that the "in XXX [unit]" usually (always?) involves an absolute measurement, not one that is relative to a certain position. You wouldn't say "I will be there in 10 minutes from now". I suppose because the "in" construction itself implies that the measurement is relative to one's position before the action occurs.[citation needed I know]

So to answer your question, for those two sentences you would say

> "**There is a lion 10 meters from you**"

and

> "**The truck had stopped several meters from me**"

unless you meant something more specialized than those sentences suggest.

Comment: @Rossitten Just a minor correction of Rozenn's answer: You wouldn't ever say "within 10 meters from you" but instead "within 10 meters _of_ you".

Comment: @Spencer thank you, my mistake I corrected it (and also added some grammatical speculation that I will look for references on later, unless someone is kind enough to give them/correct me in comments).